# I am using [(ngModel)] in an Angular 6 form, but on route change the form fields are not clearing

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using `[(ngModel)]` in a form input field in my Angular 6 application. It is working fine, but when I go to another route and then come back to the same route, the form fields remain filled and are not clearing. My form fields like:

```
`<input [(ngModel)]='user.name' matInput placeholder="Enter name" formControlName="name">`.
```

I am using a reactive form with a model and setting the value to model attributes by using `[(ngModel)]`.

I tried using `[ngModel]`, but it didn't bind the data. `[ngModel]` is not working.

```
<input [ngModel]='user.name' matInput placeholder="Enter name" formControlName="name">
```

Here `user` is an object and I am trying to bind the value to the `name` attribute of the `user` object. It is working with `[(ngModel)]`, but on route change the form fields are not clearing. I think this is happening because of two way binding. When I use `[ngModel]` to avoid two way binding, on route change the form goes clear, but the data is not binding to the object attribute. `user` object attribute `name` remains undefined.

Comment: can you add some more code

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on how and where this property is set and how you are routing? And are you using template-driven or reactive forms? You have attributes for both here.

Comment: please post some relevant code to trouble shoot

Comment: I would suggest you to not mix reactive and ngModel approaches together. 
If you want to set data into form use yourForm.patchValue or yourForm.setValue methods.

Comment: Also with a reactiveForm approach to get data back to user, you need to set it manually from form. but yes, add relative code to understand you question better...